# Определение процедуры в спецификации пакета (PLS-00302 component <procedure name> must be declared)

Tags: oracle, plsql

Есть процедура, которая определенна только в теле пакета. Её надо будет запустить по графику в JOB.

Необходимо ли определять эту процедуру в спецификации пакета или для запуска с помощью JOB в этом нет необходимости?

JOB и пакет будут определены в одной и той же схеме.

Comment: А как вы запускаете сейчас и как вы собираетесь запустить с помощью job? Пока не понятно, какие трудности у вас возникли.

Comment: Если запускать процедуру скриптом, получаю ошибку: 
PLS-00302 component <procedure name> must be declared.

Comment: А что вы обычно делаете, если получаете ошибку?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обратится вне пакета к идентификатору, стоящему после имени пакета и точки `<пакет>.`, будь то переменная, константа, процедура и тд, **можно только**, если этот идентификатор *объявлен в спецификации пакета*, исключений нет.

```
create or replace package pack as
end;
/
create or replace package body pack as
    procedure proc (par1 int) is
    begin 
        dbms_output.put_line ('procedure proc('||par1||') executed'); 
    end;
end;
/
exec pack.proc
```

> PLS-00302: component 'PROC' must be declared

Если появляется задача запустить уже сушествующую внутреннею функцию или процедуру извне, их декларацию надо поместить в специфиацию. Обычно, чтобы подогнать под контекст вызова для них пишется новая публичная "обёртка":

```
create or replace package pack as
    procedure procWrapper;
end;
/
create or replace package body pack as
    var1 int := 99;
    procedure proc (par1 int);
    procedure procWrapper is 
    begin
        proc (var1); 
    end;
    procedure proc (par1 int) is
    begin 
        dbms_output.put_line ('procedure proc('||par1||') executed'); 
    end;
end;
/
exec pack.procWrapper
```

> procedure proc(99) executed